# Redshift elastic resizing-- how difficult to downgrade a cluster?

Tags: amazon-redshift

We're using a dc2.large cluster size with two nodes in Redshift.  We would like to 'try out' a four node cluster to see how the performance is.

According to the Redshift dashboard it'll take about 10-15 minutes to do an elastic resize, while the cluster is in read-only mode.  My question is, if the performance isn't what we were hoping how long does it take to downsize back to two nodes, has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10-15 is on the high side. Typically takes just a few minutes to size up or **down**. You can even schedule the resize up and down to happen whenever you want to (e.g. scale down or pause overnight).